# как сохранять данные в C#

Tags: c#

Как сохранять данные в программе? Например, если у меня консольное приложение и я собираюсь считать свой бюджет и каждый раз, открывая программу я буду добавлять или отнимать деньги со своего бюджета.

Comment: используй базу данных или пиши в файл и при открытии приложения читай с файла данные

Comment: @SultanovShamil: База данных что-то слишком просто. Давайте сразу предложим микросервисную архитектуру, чего уж там мелочиться?

Comment: @VladD я ж написал как вариант писать в файл и считывать, к чему здесь излишний сарказм, пусть учится

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала можно попробовать сериализацию в XML. Привёл полный пример кода.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //string directory = Path.Combine(
            //    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "ProgramName");
            string directory = Path.Combine("D:\\", "ProgramName");
            string file = Path.Combine(directory, "data.xml");

            Data data = new Data
            {
                Amount = 150m
            };

            Display(data, "Исходный вариант");
            try
            {
                if (!Directory.Exists(directory))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);
                }
                Serializer.SaveToXml(file, data);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }

            // Как будто читаем где-то в другом месте программы и не сразу же после записи
            // -----------------------------
            try
            {
                Data fromFile = null;
                if (File.Exists(file))
                {
                    fromFile = Serializer.LoadXml<Data>(file);
                }
                else
                {
                    fromFile = new Data();
                }

                Display(fromFile, "Прочитанный из файла");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void Display(Data data, string message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(message + ". Amount: {0}", data.Amount);
        }
    }

    public class Data
    {
        public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    }

    public static class Serializer
    {
        public static void SaveToXml<T>(String fileName, T serializableObject)
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            using (TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(fileName))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(textWriter, serializableObject);
            }
        }

        public static T LoadXml<T>(String fileName)
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            using (TextReader textReader = new StreamReader(fileName))
            {
                return (T)serializer.Deserialize(textReader);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: объясните ламеру чем xml лучше текстового файла?

Comment: @epsilon, тем что это уже структурированный файл, и в xml можно сеарилизовать/десериализовать (записать и считать) объект, т.е. нет необходимости изобретать велосипед и придумывать свой собственный формат, да и использовать удобней

Comment: @max619 спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Существует много способов, но на мой взгляд самый простой - используя EntityFramework и подход Code First.

CodeFirst удобен тем, что вам ненужно самостоятельно создавать базу, она будет создана автоматически при первом входе в программу и дальше вы будете с ней работать.

Создаёте класс для работы с бюджетом. Все методы и необходимые поля (количество средств, операция со средствами, дата операции, описание)

Создаёте проект, подключаете EF через nuget package.

Далее создаём класс для работы с бюджетом. На моём примере вышло что-то такое

```
class BudgetUnit
{
    // Для работы с БД имя одного из полей должно заканчиваться на "id"
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int changeInAmount { get; set; }
    public DateTime dt { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }

    // Также необходимо наличие пустого конструктора
    public BudgetUnit()
    { }        

    // Конструктор опционально
    public BudgetUnit(int changeInAmount, string description)
    {
       this.changeInAmount = changeInAmount;
       this.description = description;

       dt = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

Далее для работы с БД необходимо создать класс-контекст, почитать об этом можно например вот тут: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext(v=vs.113).aspx

---

У меня получилось нечто такое:

```
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace Budget
{
  class BudgetUnitContext : DbContext
  {
    // Пустой конструктор. "DbConnection" - имя соединения настроим чуть 
    // ниже. 
    public BudgetUnitContext()
      : base("DbConnection")
    { }

    public DbSet<BudgetUnit> Units { get; set; }
  }
}
```

Далее необходимо зайти в App.config найти там закрывающий тег

```
</ConfigSections>
```

и добавить после него строку подключения с именем "DbConnection":

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DBConnection" connectionString="data source=
    (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=userstore.mdf;Integrated 
    Security=True;"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Собственно это всё что нужно для сохранения данных в БД. Осталось использовать полученный механизм в программе:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

  // Внесение данных
  using (BudgetUnitContext db = new BudgetUnitContext())
  {
    BudgetUnit bu1 = new BudgetUnit(35000, "Аванс");
    BudgetUnit bu2 = new BudgetUnit(15000, "Сосед вернул долг");
    BudgetUnit bu3 = new BudgetUnit(-12000, "Покупка пароварки");

    db.Units.Add(bu1);
    db.Units.Add(bu2);
    db.Units.Add(bu3);

    db.SaveChanges();
    Console.WriteLine("Объекты добавлены");

    // Можно получать данные в этом же блоке, но для наглядности вынесу в отдельный
  }

  // Получение данных
  using (BudgetUnitContext db = new BudgetUnitContext())
  {
    var units = db.Units;
    Console.WriteLine("Список объектов");
    int money = 0;
    foreach (BudgetUnit u in units)
    {
      money += u.changeInAmount;
      Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}, {2} - {3}, остаток средств {4}", u.Id, 
          u.dt, u.changeInAmount, u.description, money);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: >>учусь писать на C# да и программировать в целом<< Не жестоко ли? Вот так сразу на ORM...

Comment: А я всегда думал, что файл -- самый простой способ.

Comment: Вы уверены, что это _самое подходящее_ решение для консольной утилиты новичка?

Comment: Небольшое количество кода, и освоение EF в одном флаконе ) ну возможно я и правда перегнул